# How to make EMP-Immune electronics?

Tags: hard-science, electromagnetism

Is there a theoretical way to make electronics to be physically immune to any EMP, no matter how strong?

If there is a way then drones have no more disadvantages, that would warrant the use of  human operated combat vehicles.

Comment: Faraday shield. In theory and practice. This is question more suited for physics.se.

Comment: Faraday cages will suffer potentially disruptive current flows and arcing if subjected to suitable electrical fields, and high frequency EM can penetrate any gaps in the shield (of the sort you'll probably need in order to interface the electronics with a working drone).

Comment: There is a dedicated Wikipedia page on the topic. -1 for lack of research effort.

Comment: -1 for condescension. Why should I browse wikipedia through multiple articles looking for this very specific info when I can get a more direct answer here(I could find no "dedicated" wikipedia page on EMP immune electronics)? This isn't a thesis for my  major that I am gonna spend hours of my time researching. Also, you seem to have answered questions that also have dedicated pages on wikipedia, yet you did not downvote them.

Comment: It all depends on what is considered an EMP, and what *"no matter how strong"* actually means. With common-sense limitations, electronics are routinely made [EMP resistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_compatibility) for those applications (e.g., military) which require it.

Comment: Since we help you with your worldbuilding problem it's just polite to put some effort on your own in doing some research, and show those effort in the question itself. In this case the search would have answered your question completely.

Comment: @A.boj "*Why should I browse wikipedia through multiple articles looking for this very specific info when I can get a more direct answer here*" because Worldbuilding.SE is not just a slightly more convenient search box. We aren't here to do your research but help you build a world.

Comment: Sorry magnetic line of force cannot be destroyed so your shielding isn't perfect.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a theoretical way to make electronics to be physically immune to any EMP, no matter how strong?

Yes. [Fluidics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluidics) is probably the most robust option. Not necessarily suitable for making control systems for compact robots, though, which is presumably what you *really* wanted... [microfluidic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microfluidics) systems are small, but still many thousands of times larger than a modern integrated circuit, and a lot slower, too. There's also the option of engineering an organic neural network, as natural brains seem to be able to fit quite complex behaviours into quite small spaces, but you end up basically just making a bird once you've solved all the rest of the problems...

> If there is a way then drones have no more disadvantages,

You'll also be wanting to find a non-electrical power supply for them, and non-electrical motors, too. So yeah, just engineer some birds, maybe.

Note though that EMP ain't the only way to take out a drone, not by a long shot. Or a bird, for that matter.

[image: Eagle hunting drone]

(from a [bbc](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/av/world-europe-35750816/eagles-trained-to-take-down-drones) article on a company training eagles to hunt drones)

Comment: Im talking about making EMP immune, unmanned tanks, ships, spacecraft, etc, not just drones. Why is it impossible to make completely EMP immune electronics?

Comment: @A.boj but you _weren't_ talking about that in your question. If that's what you wanted, you should have made it clear. An explanation as to the _whys_ of EMP will not reasonably fit in an SE comment, but suffice to say that strong electrical field plus conductors plus components that can be damaged by voltage spikes means that EMP resistance can never be perfect in any electrical system. Non-voltage-sensitive components are generally much too big for integrated circuits, so tradeoffs have to be made.

Comment: Drone is another word for any unmanned vehicle. Thx for the answer.